# Matrix Rotations and Enlargements Help

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Matrix $M$ is given as \begin{bmatrix}3&-{\sqrt 7}\\{\sqrt 7}&3\end{bmatrix} I then am asked to describe the transformation, you are also told dis an enlargement followed by a rotation and you must find these two, I notice that that the rotation matrix can't be used as $\cos( \theta ) \neq 3$ etc. I found a way that then says what you can do is assume $\cos(\theta) = \frac{3}{h} $ and $\sin(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt 7}{h}$ After this you construct a triangle with $Adj = 3$ and $Opp=\sqrt 7$ and solve for the $hyp$ giving $4$. After this you are left with this:
$\begin{bmatrix}4&{0}\\{0}&4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{4}&{\frac{-\sqrt7}{4}}\\{\frac{\sqrt7}{4}}&\frac{3}{4}\end{bmatrix}$ giving the final answer, Its one thing being told it, but Id like to know why this works, I was told it's a neat "trick".
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) corresponding to angle $\theta$ has the form

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{array}\right)$$

All that you're doing is pulling out a common term of $4 = \sqrt{3^2 + \sqrt{7}^2}$ to recognize each entry as a quotient of sides in a triangle. For example, in your setup, $3/4 = \text{adj} / \text{hyp} = \cos \theta$.

The purpose of the matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \end{array}\right)$$
is just to encode this "pulling out a common term of $4$," since it's just four times the identity matrix. Hence, it scales up by factor $4$. You could just as well have written

$$M = 4 \left(\begin{array}{cc} 3/4 & -\sqrt 7 / 4 \\ \sqrt{7} / 4 & 3 \end{array}\right)$$
but the advantage to the way in your post is that a product of *matrices* can be interpreted as a composition of two transformations.